# creating kubernetes pods without using any public/private docker registory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, kubernetes-pod, docker-repository

with a new release of our product, we want to move to new technologies(kubernetes) so that we can take advantage of it services. we have a local kubernetes application running in our infra. we have made our applicatons dockerize and now we want to use the images to integrate it with kubernetes to make cluster --pods,
but we are stuck with docker registry as our customer do not want to have any public/private docker repository(registry) where we can upload this images. we have try with (docker save and docker load) but no luck(error: portal-66d9f557bb-dc6kq 0/1 ImagePullBackOff) Is it at all possible to have some filesystem where from we can access this images or any other alternative is welcome if that solves our problems(no private/public repository/registry).

Comment: Why don't you want to use docker registry?

Comment: It is the customer, who don't want to maintain docker registry or they don't want have the same.

Comment: But even if you make some kind of file system storage, that too has to be maintained (Eg mounting of network volume into build runners etc).

Comment: yes, true will that resolves my problem, maybe I am using the wrong syntax => image: destination_of_the_images/images_name. please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

A Docker registry of some sort is all but a requirement to run Kubernetes.  Paid Docker Hub supports private images; Google and Amazon both have hosted registry products (GCR and ECR respectively); there are third-party registries; or you can deploy the [official registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) locally.

There's an alternative path where you [`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) every private image you reference in any Kubernetes pod spec, then [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it on every single node.  This has obvious scale and maintenance problems (whenever *anybody* updates *any* image you need to redeploy it by hand to *every* node).  But if you really need to try this, make sure your pod specs specify `ImagePullPolicy: Never` to avoid trying to fetch things from registries.  (If something isn't present on a node the pod will just fail to start up.)

The [registry](https://github.com/docker/distribution) is "just" an open-source (Go) HTTP REST service that implements the Docker registry API, if that helps your deployment story.

Comment: but in this case, I have to use docker public/private registry or some 3rd party hub to resolve the issue.